# Android WebView doesn't work on android 4.4

Tags: android, webview, android-4.4-kitkat, egl

I am developing an application where I am using a webview. Everything is working fine on my Lg-p880 with android 4.1 but on the new Kitkat phones ( and also the Emulator) the Logcat shows me :

> 01-29 11:16:03.095: E/eglCodecCommon(2179): **** ERROR unknown type
>   0x10037 (glSizeof,72)

and

> 01-29 11:16:03.695: E/eglCodecCommon(2179): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44

If I comment this Line it works but (logically) not showing anything.

```
view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/index.html");
```

I haven't found anything on Google, please help me
and thanks in advance

Comment: Please notice that from KitKat the WebView has been completely changed and it's now based on Chromium. Did your HTML code do something in particular? Please read this guide: http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html.

Comment: Beyond that, feel free to provide the rest of your `WebView` configuration code and, more importantly, the HTML that is failing.

Answer (score 1):

According to Google's documentation, you should expect problems with running Blink-based WebView and Chrome/ium on the Emulator because of inconsistencies in the support of OpenGL-ES, specifically problems with EGL support.

Quite honestly this is a real problem since it appears you need a physical KitKat device to test WebView application applications which use EGL, such as playing media, even though simple HTML5 interfaces work quite well.